# Right alignment of minipages inside fbox

Tags: minipage, fbox

I am using fbox together with minipage, inside the minipage I have multicols and enumerate environments. Its not a big issue but I noticed the boxes are not aligned on the right. I tried using \linewidth instead of \textwidth but I still get the same results. Any ideas or suggestions on how to align the boxes on both the left and the right?

Below is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\small
\subsection*{Answer sheet}
\noindent\textsc{Name:} $\rule{2.9in}{0.15mm}$\hfill\textsc{Student Number:} $\rule{1.5in}{0.15mm}$
\vspace{2mm}
\\
\noindent\textsc{Instructor:} $\rule{2.6in}{0.15mm} $\hfill\textsc{Class Section: }$\rule{1.5in}{0.15mm}$
\normalsize
\newline \\
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\vspace{1mm}
\textbf{Part 1. Matching type.}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\vspace{1mm}
\end{minipage}}%
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\vspace{1mm}
\textbf{Part 2. True or False.}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item    
\end{enumerate}    
\end{multicols}
\vspace{1mm}
\end{minipage}}
\newline
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}
\vspace{1mm}
\textbf{Part 3. Multiple Choice.}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item      
\end{enumerate}    
\end{multicols}
\vspace{1mm}
\end{minipage}}
\newline
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}
\vspace{1mm}
\textbf{Part 4. Problem 1. Fill in the blanks.}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item [(a)] 
    \item [(b)]
    \item [(c)] 
    \item [(d)]
    \item [(e)] 
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{1mm}
\end{minipage}
}
\newline
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}
\vspace{1mm}
\textbf{Part 4. Problem 2. Fill in the blanks.}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item [(a)]   
    \item [(b)] 
    \item [(c)] 
    \item [(d)] 
    \item [(e)]
    \item [(f)] 
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{1mm}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Mini pages width widths are to big. At defining them you should considered `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule` and accordingly reduce thair widths-
- Code lines (in MWE marked by `<---`) at end of `\end{minipage}}` and `\fbox{` should be terminated by `%` \end{minipage}}.

Considering above mentioned, your MWE should be:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\small
\subsection*{Answer sheet}
\noindent\textsc{Name:} $\rule{2.9in}{0.15mm}$\hfill\textsc{Student Number:} $\rule{1.5in}{0.15mm}$
\vspace{2mm}
\\
\noindent\textsc{Instructor:} $\rule{2.6in}{0.15mm} $\hfill\textsc{Class Section: }$\rule{1.5in}{0.15mm}$
\normalsize
\newline \\
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
\vspace{1mm}
\textbf{Part 1. Matching type.}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\vspace{1mm}
\end{minipage}}%    <---
\fbox{%             <---
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule} %    <---
\vspace{1mm}
\textbf{Part 2. True or False.}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\vspace{1mm}
\end{minipage}}%    <---
\newline
\fbox{%             <---
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%    <---
\vspace{1mm}
\textbf{Part 3. Multiple Choice.}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\vspace{1mm}
\end{minipage}}%    <---
\newline
\fbox{%             <---
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%    <---
\vspace{1mm}
\textbf{Part 4. Problem 1. Fill in the blanks.}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item [(a)]
    \item [(b)]
    \item [(c)]
    \item [(d)]
    \item [(e)]
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{1mm}
\end{minipage}}%    <---
\newline
\fbox{%             <---
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%    <---
\vspace{1mm}
\textbf{Part 4. Problem 2. Fill in the blanks.}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item [(a)]
    \item [(b)]
    \item [(c)]
    \item [(d)]
    \item [(e)]
    \item [(f)]
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{1mm}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not a guru solution, only a trial and error one:

[image]

Code (little corrections of proposed code):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
    \small
    \subsection*{Answer sheet}
    \noindent\textsc{Name:} $\rule{2.9in}{0.15mm}$\hfill\textsc{Student Number:} $\rule{1.5in}{0.15mm}$
    \vspace{2mm}
    \\
    \noindent\textsc{Instructor:} $\rule{2.6in}{0.15mm} $\hfill\textsc{Class Section: }$\rule{1.5in}{0.15mm}$
    \normalsize
    \newline \\
    \fbox{
        \begin{minipage}{7.98cm}
            \vspace{1mm}
            \textbf{Part 1. Matching type.}
            \begin{multicols}{2}
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item
                \end{enumerate}
            \end{multicols}
            \vspace{1mm}
    \end{minipage}}%
    \fbox{
        \begin{minipage}{7.98cm}
            \vspace{1mm}
            \textbf{Part 2. True or False.}
            \begin{multicols}{2}
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item    
                \end{enumerate}    
            \end{multicols}
            \vspace{1mm}
    \end{minipage}}
    \newline
    \fbox{
        \begin{minipage}{16.31 cm}
            \vspace{1mm}
            \textbf{Part 3. Multiple Choice.}
            \begin{multicols}{3}
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item 
                    \item      
                \end{enumerate}    
            \end{multicols}
            \vspace{1mm}
    \end{minipage}}
    \newline
    \fbox{
        \begin{minipage}{16.2cm}
            \vspace{1mm}
            \textbf{Part 4. Problem 1. Fill in the blanks.}
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item [(a)] 
                \item [(b)]
                \item [(c)] 
                \item [(d)]
                \item [(e)] 
            \end{enumerate}
            \vspace{1mm}
        \end{minipage}
    }
    \newline
    \fbox{
        \begin{minipage}{16.2cm}
            \vspace{1mm}
            \textbf{Part 4. Problem 2. Fill in the blanks.}
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item [(a)]   
                \item [(b)] 
                \item [(c)] 
                \item [(d)] 
                \item [(e)]
                \item [(f)] 
            \end{enumerate}
            \vspace{1mm}
        \end{minipage}
    }
\end{document}
```